# Воспроизвести переход на грегорианский календарь

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня не получается воспроизвести переход в РСФСР на грегорианский календарь. Пробую самым простым способом вычесть из даты 14 февраля 1918 года несколько дней и получаю "несуществующие" даты.

```
SELECT to_char(to_date('14.02.1918', 'DD.MM.RRRR') - 5, 'DD.MM.RRRR') my_date
  FROM dual;
```

Установка

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'RUSSIA';
```

не помогло.

Смутно помнится, что есть какие-то специальные временные зоны для этого, но не смог найти информации. Подскажите, как это сделать.

[ссылка на вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BE%D1%82_26_%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F_1918_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Comment: Поясните, что значит "несуществующие даты" ? и выполните `select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter='NLS_CALENDAR'`

Comment: "Несуществующие" - это значит, что отнимая один день (с российскими региональными настройками) от даты 14 февраля 1918 года я должен получить 31 января, а получаю 13 февраля, которого официально в календаре не существовало. Запрос из nls_session_parameters возвращает 'GREGORIAN'.

Comment: То есть 14 февраля действовал григорианский календарь, а до него был другой календарь, в котором было 31 января? Похоже, что стандартными средствами не добиться такого поведения. Что если создать свое представление с таким хитрым календарем и вертеться от него?

Comment: Только наоборот - до 31 января 1918 года всё ещё действовал юлианский календарь, а потом разом перешли на грегорианский, и 13 календарных дней (с 1 по 13 февраля включительно) просто исчезли. Мне интересно, могу ли я это воспроизвести. Вот, например, календарь на 1918 в РФ http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1918&country=20. Я уверен, что где-то в часовых поясах это должно быть, но как добраться до такого функционала через арифметику дат, понять не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В настройках `NLS_CALENDAR` у вас стоит Григорианский календарь(`GREGORIAN`). По нему 13 февраля существовало, и 12 тоже. Просто одновременно при этом по Юлианскому календарю было 31 и 30 января. В настройках NLS Оракла задать Юлианский календарь не получится.
Не важно, что выставлено в  `NLS_TERRITORY`, календарь универсальный для всего мира. Часовые пояса тут тоже не помогут.

Решением проблемы может быть создание своего альтернативного календаря, в котором эти дни будут отсутствовать.

Answer (score 2):

Можно получить искомые даты используя `CASE`

```
WITH dates AS
  (
    SELECT TO_DATE('25.01.1918', 'DD.MM.YYYY') + ROWNUM dt
      FROM dual
   CONNECT BY level < 30
     ORDER BY dt desc
  )    
SELECT dt gregorian,
       CASE WHEN dt < TO_DATE('14.02.1918', 'DD.MM.YYYY') 
         THEN dt - 13 
         ELSE dt 
       END our
  FROM dates
```