# Запрос для вывода временных интервалов

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

Как написать запрос, выводящий заданые временные интервалы за определённый промежуток времени, например, за календарный год?

Пример формата вывода:

```
2017.01.01 01:00:00
2017.01.01 01:15:00
…..
2017.12.31 23:30:00
2017.12.31 23:45:00
```

Comment: connect by отсюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491410/194569 возьмите, только решите что к начальной дате добавлять, что бы получить те интервалы которые вам нужны.

Comment: @Mike Моих поверхностных познаний не хватает, чтобы осилить предложенное. Есть какой-либо менее красивый, но более тривиальный вариант?

Comment: либо таблица со всеми значениями либо рекурсивный cte, но он более громоздкий. И вы так и не сказали какого размера этот самый интервал, 15 минут что ли ?

Comment: Те даты, что вы привели - это исходные данные или результат? По-хорошему, надо и то, и другое, и объяснить, в чем логика превращения одного в другое.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select TO_DATE('2017010101','YYYYMMDDHH')+(level-1)/(24*4)
  from DUAL
connect by TO_DATE('2017010101','YYYYMMDDHH')+(level-1)/(24*4) < DATE'2018-01-01'
```

Так как арифметика дат у Oracle идет в днях, делитель для порядкового номера в рекурсии (level) берется так, что бы в результате получилась нужная часть дня. В нашем случае 15 минут это день деленный на 24 часа и еще на 4 части.

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from table(getDateInterval (date'2017-01-01', date'2017-12-31', 1/24/60*15));

2017-01-01  00:00:00
2017-01-01  00:15:00
2017-01-01  00:30:00
...
2017-12-31  23:15:00
2017-12-31  23:30:00
2017-12-31  23:45:00
```

Сама функция:

```
create or replace function getDateInterval (fromDate date, toDate date, timeSpan int) return sys.ODCIDateList pipelined is
begin
    for r in (
        with cteDates (cteDate) as ( 
            select fromDate cteDate 
            from dual
            union all
            select cteDate + timeSpan
            from cteDates
            where cteDate + timeSpan < toDate + 1  
            )
        select cteDate from cteDates 
        order by cteDate 
    ) loop pipe row(r.cteDate); end loop;
    return;
end;
/
```

Для тех, у кого к несчастью стоит 11.2.0.2, следуюший воркароунд в RCTE:

```
with cteDates (cteDate) as ( 
    select cast(to_date('2017.12.31 23:45:00', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') as date) cteDate 
    from dual
    union all
    select  cast((cteDate - (1/24/60)*15) as date)  cteDate
    from cteDates
    where cast(cteDate as date) > to_date('2017.01.01 01:00:00', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss')
    )
select * from cteDates 
order by cteDate 
;
```

На первый взгляд безсмысленная конструкция `cast date as date` и обратная рекурсия необходимы из-за бага в рекурсивных CTE. Дискуссии см. [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509494/generate-range-of-dates-using-cte-oracle/42518626#42518626) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586653/recursive-sql-giving-ora-01790).  В 12c или пропатченной 11g будет работать без них (см. выше).